# What does having a + sign in front of a number do?

Tags: ios, objective-c, operators

I was looking over someone's code just barely and I saw something I haven't seen before:

`CGSizeMake(+(rect.size.width*0.3f), +(rect.size.height*0.3f));`

Seems like a silly question but I've just never seen it done before. Does this just ensure that the value is positive? Like `-` ensures negativity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They do nothing.  They don't ensure positive.  They are superfluous.  Here is some code and corresponding output:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 10, 20, 20);
CGSize boo = CGSizeMake(+(rect.size.width*0.3f), +(rect.size.height*0.3f));
NSLog(@"Boo+ is %f, %f", boo.width, boo.height);

rect = CGRectMake(0, 10, -20, -20);
boo = CGSizeMake(+(rect.size.width*0.3f), +(rect.size.height*0.3f));
NSLog(@"Boo is %f, %f", boo.width, boo.height);


rect = CGRectMake(0, 10, 20, 20);
CGSize hoo = CGSizeMake((rect.size.width*0.3f), (rect.size.height*0.3f));
NSLog(@"Hoo+ is %f, %f", hoo.width, hoo.height);

rect = CGRectMake(0, 10, -20, -20);
hoo = CGSizeMake((rect.size.width*0.3f), (rect.size.height*0.3f));
NSLog(@"Hoo is %f, %f", hoo.width, hoo.height);
```

output:

```
2013-12-30 23:16:08.446 RAACTutor[7730:1c103] Boo+ is 6.000000, 6.000000
2013-12-30 23:16:08.449 RAACTutor[7730:1c103] Boo is -6.000000, -6.000000
2013-12-30 23:16:08.451 RAACTutor[7730:1c103] Hoo+ is 6.000000, 6.000000
2013-12-30 23:16:08.452 RAACTutor[7730:1c103] Hoo is -6.000000, -6.000000
```

As you can see, it has no impact at all.  It is most likely a relic of some more extensive calculations in a previous incarnation of that CGSizeMake.

Comment: You mean there is no use of plus symbol then why it used ?

Comment: It really does nothing.  It has no effect on the final result.  As you see from my example, it signifies nothing, because if you come into it with negative values, you will get a negative result.

Answer (score 4):

Its a Mathematics with proper notation. It just clarifies that the product of the math inside the parenthesis will be positive(or assumes to be positive).

So if I look at this code I know the product of multiplication will be positive.

Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/eNXLW/

I just wrote an alert statement in javascript.

```
alert(+4 * +5);
```

Which normally we write it like,

```
alert(4*5);
```

Similarly, the programmer is ust telling other programmers that the end result will be positive.

Comment: As a mathematician, I'd have to disagree with you on the "proper notation" comment.  That makes no sense, as the end result may very well be negative, because the width and height can be anything.  If you really want to guarantee a positive result for "+(rect.size.width*0.3f)", you would need to use fabs(rect.size.width*0.3f) or some other absolute value function.